# I cannot get the embedded images to display in (Xamarin Forms Application)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to make a very simple cross-platform application in Xamarin Froms using Visual studio 2017. The purpose of the app is to show Food recipes in small GridViews, with Name of the Recipe, and its picture.

I used the following static class file to add data for recipes. (**RecipeData.cs**)

```
**// Class that adds  Data to Recipe Items**
public static class RecipeData
{
  static List<Recipe> _allRecipes;

    public static List<Recipe> AllRecipes
    {
        //List<Recipe> _allRecipes = new List<Recipe>();
        get
        {

            if(_allRecipes == null)
            {
                _allRecipes = new List<Recipe>
                {
                    new Recipie
                    {
                        RecipeName="Eggs Benedict",
                        CookTime = "24 min",
                        PreprationTime = "5 min",
                        NumberOfServing = 8,
                        WillMakeAgain = true,
                        MealType = MealType.Breakfast,
                        Difficulty = Difficulty.Easy,
                        Directions="1. Fill a large saucepan with about 4 inches of water, add vinegar, and bring to a boil. Fill a shallow dish or pie plate with warm water. Reduce heat under saucepan to medium, so water is just barely simmering. Break 1 egg at a time into a small heat-proof bowl. Gently tip bowl into water; carefully slide egg into water. Repeat with remaining eggs.\n\n2. When eggs begin to become opaque, remove them from the saucepan with a slotted spoon in the order in which they were added. Transfer the eggs to the dish of warm water. This process should take about 3 minutes.\n\n3. Prepare the hollandaise sauce, and set aside, keeping it warm.\n\n4. Heat a medium skillet over medium heat. Add Canadian bacon, and cook until well browned on both sides. Divide bacon among the English-muffin halves. For each serving, use a slotted spoon to remove one egg from warm water; set spoon and egg briefly on a clean cloth or paper towel to drain. Gently place the egg on a bacon-topped muffin, and spoon the reserved warm hollandaise sauce over the top.",
                        Ingredients="1 tablespoon white vinegar" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "8 large eggs\nHollandaise Sauce" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "1/2 pound (16 slices) Canadian bacon" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "4 English muffins, split in half, toasted",
                        ImageName = "Muffin.jpg"
                    },
```

Here is what my Project looks Files look like:

[image: screen shot of my current project files (shows that i have the Muffin.jpg Picture]

Screen shot of my current project files (shows that i have the Muffin.jpg Picture)

To convert the string value to Image type I am using the **ImageBindingConver class**

```
class ImageBindingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string Assembly { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var source = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            return null;

        var imagePath = $"{Assembly}.{source}";

        return ImageSource.FromResource(imagePath);

    }
```

**This the Xaml file for the recipe class**
[RecipiePage.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrsEf.png)
These are all the pages I am using to display the RecipePage but the images dont showup and neither do i get any error message. I have been spending a lot of time on it if someone can help it would be great. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you did change the Build Action of the image to EmbededResource in Visual Studio.

Next you need to change the image path. By default VS or XS will concatenate using a dot '.' the Assembly Name + Any Folder the image lives in + the image name with the extension, in your case the image name should be:

```
var imagePath = $"{Assembly}.Images.{source}";
```

You can confirm what is the Resource Id of that image looking at its properties.

More of embedded images can be seen [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @apineda. If you read teh Recipie Page.Xaml file i provided I added the assembly name and set its path to Images folder. I had also image buid action to Embedded resource. but the images dont show up I tried the solution with an another project with very similar files and images showed up there but not in this project.

Comment: I think the problem is with the File structure the images folder is not being called correctly or i have wrong assembly

Comment: @oopragmmer Is the other projec you tried (and worked) also a shared project ?

Comment: so I believe the problem might be there.. Shared project structures are... different.. they are actually not a project, as they don't build, there are more like a way to "link" files to different projects but the files itselfs are not part of the Shared project but part of the other project. In this case your path should point to the Android namespace when running from Android.